# Control synergy programmatically

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, synergy, dwm

I'm trying to toggle **switchInDirection()** from a window manager (dwm, written in c). As there seems to be no way to control synergy actions from the command line, I tried to fire appropriate key combinations from the wm.

Scenario: on `super+,`(comma) event, which is caught by the wm, it should fire another keycombo that synergys is listening for. For some reason `XTestFakeKeyEvent` (xlib function) didn't work at all, and simulating keypress with `XSendEvent` doesn't work with modifiers, so I had to make a system call to xdotool:

```
xdotool keyup comma key control+alt+shift+F11 // note the required comma key up;
```

It seems to work as a POC, but at some point it'll cause segfault in synergys. Note that triggering the same keycombo without xdotool does not result in segfault.

What, if any, options do I have?

**Edit:**
one obvious solution would be listening to the `super+,` event with synergy in the first place, and handling the logic there (whether switch screen or send another keycombo to dwm). This should work, but implies different dwm configurations for server and client, as `super+,` should still be handled by dwm in the client (otherwise controlling client via its native keyboard wouldn't work as expected).